# Can't synchronize time in Ubuntu (Europe/Moscow)

Tags: ubuntu, time, timezone, time-synchronization

I've got this Ubuntu server virtual machine. I'm trying to setup a correct time on it.

I've selected a proper timezone (`Europe > Moscow`) via `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`.

After that, I'm using the following command to synchronize the time: `sudo ntpdate 0.ru.pool.ntp.org`. However, time is not sets correctly. It's ahead of actual time in Moscow by one hour.

Formally speaking, Moscow time is `UTC+4` without `DST`. However, on `26 of October` the Russian government decided to shift time one hour backward.

How do I deal with this situation? Is there a changes in World's time synchronization infrastructure that should be done according to this change?

Answer (score 1):

The routine software update helped to resolve this issue. It looks like new information about time change in Russia were contained in latest `tzdata` package update.